# Updating an object using mongoose

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose

I'm trying to update an object inside my database using this code.

```js
if (args[1] === 'set'){
            serverModel.findOneAndUpdate(
                {serverID: message.guild.id},
                {$set: {'restraints.channel': message.channel.id}}
            )
        }
```

The problem is that, while the code runs without error, nothing in the database has been updated.

It follows this model, yet I can't seem to update 'channel':

```js
const serverSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    serverID: {type: String, require: true, unique: true},
    restraints: {type: Object, require: true, default: {channel: null, locked: false, announce: null}}
});
```

Answer (score 0):

`serverModel.findOneAndUpdate()` doesn't do anything other than return a [`Query`](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/query.html).

A query needs to get executed before anything happens to your database.

There are various way to do that:

```
// preferred way:
await serverModel.findOneAndUpdate(…)

// OR, pass a callback:
serverModel.findOneAndUpdate(…, (err, doc) => { … })

// OR, just execute it and ignore the outcome:
serverModel.findOneAndUpdate(…).exec();
```

Comment: Hi.
I tried this but it still doesn't update the object.
I have also tried `'restraints.$.channel'` if that makes any difference, but to no avail.
[Here](https://prnt.sc/XtS_io6IW0dS) is an image of the object I'm accessing and [this image](https://prnt.sc/WGQrMo-mUgC7) contains the 'channel' value that I want change, if visual representation helps any.

Comment: It should work with `restraints.channel`. Are you sure that `message.guild.id` matches your document (and that `message.channel.id` is valid, too)?

Comment: I double checked that `message.guild.id` is the same, and it was. I also forced all occurences of it to string, which is the stored type, but that didn't change anything either.
`message.channel.id` is also valid, as it is used both above and below the code in question.
My guess is that it doesn't find the document, because I can't change any other value but I don't know why. I can modify another collection that I use without trouble, however.

Comment: You can try and see if `serverModel.find({ serverID: message.guild.id })` yields any results. I don't see anything inherently wrong (although, formally, `type : Object` isn't supported by Mongoose I think) and I tried your schema/model locally, which works fine (updates as well). Just to be sure: you're checking the actual database to see if the changes are made, correct? Because `findOneAndUpdate()` will, by default, return the _old_ (not updated) version of the document.

Comment: Using just `serverModel.find(...)` returns both the `serverID` string and the `restraints` object, so it seems like it does find the collection. And yes, I'm checking the actual database through Studio 3T and refreshing/reloading the documents in every way possible when I try to update the restraints.

Comment: Strange. Like I said, with your schema and the suggested code in my answer, updates work perfectly fine. Your Mongoose code doesn't use any hooks/middleware or anything? Have you tried running just the minimal amount of code to see if that fails too? With hardcoded values for the id's.